# In SharePoint 2013 pragmatically how to copy document Library Item from one site collection to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2013, document-library

I have 2 site collection of same web application as site1 & site2.
I have create Document Library on both site as Doc1 & Doc2.when Item is uploaded in Documemnt Library then copy that item into site2 Doc2 Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace CopyListItems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSite mySourceSite = new SPSite("http://fivenumber:5/");
                SPWeb mySourceWeb = mySourceSite.OpenWeb();
                SPList mySourceList = mySourceWeb.Lists["Source List"];
                SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();
                mySourceListQuery.Query = "" +
                                "" +
                                "" +
                                "" +
                                "";
                SPListItemCollection mySourceItemColl = mySourceList.GetItems(mySourceListQuery);
                int count = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem mySourceListItem in mySourceItemColl)
                {
                    string SourceEmpId = mySourceListItem["Employee Id"].ToString();
                    string SourceEmpName = mySourceListItem["Employee Name"].ToString();
                    string SourceDesig = mySourceListItem["Designation"].ToString();
                    string SourceAge = mySourceListItem["Age"].ToString();

                    SPSite myDestinationSite = new SPSite("http://fivenumber:50");
                    SPWeb myDestinationWeb = myDestinationSite.OpenWeb();
                    SPList myDestinationList = myDestinationWeb.Lists["Destination List"];
                    SPListItem myDestinationListItem = myDestinationList.Items.Add();

                    myDestinationListItem["Employee Id"] = SourceEmpId;
                    myDestinationListItem["Employee Name"] = SourceEmpName;
                    myDestinationListItem["Designation"] = SourceDesig;
                    myDestinationListItem["Age"] = SourceAge;
                    myDestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    myDestinationListItem.Update();
                    myDestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine(count+" item(s) copied");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.